# html вопрос по выводу данных

Tags: java, html, spring, hibernate

```
Ребята здравствуйте! при запросе список групп выводится HTML странице так:

ID  Surname  Firsname   Patronomic             Group
1   Adel    Beisenbina  Korganbekovna   Group(groupId=1, nameGroup=7A);
...
как убрать "Group(groupId=1, nameGroup=" и оставить только 7А?

Вот класс Student:
    public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "student_id", unique = true)
    private Long studentID;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "patronymic")
    private String patronymic;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "studentSet")
    private Set<Lesson> lessonSet = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;

    public Student(String surname, String firstname, String patronymic) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
    }

    public void addLesson(Lesson lesson){
        getLessonSet().add(lesson);
    }
    public void removeLesson(Lesson lesson){
        getLessonSet().remove(lesson);
    }
}

    класс Group:
@NoArgsConstructor
 @Data
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "group_")
 @NamedQuery(name = "Group.findByName",
        query = "select distinct c from Group c  where c.nameGroup =   
 :name")

 public class Group implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "group_id", unique = true)
    private Long groupId;
    @Column(name = "name_group")
    private String nameGroup;

    public Group(String nameGroup) {
        this.nameGroup = nameGroup;
    }

  Вот  запрос:  

    @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findAll", query = "select c from Student 
  c"),
```

Answer (score 0):

А куда выводите данные? Если в строку то надо переопределить метод toString() в объекте Group.

```
@Override toString(){return nameGroup;}
```

Comment: выводить html страницу. toString переопределен аннотацией.

Comment: На предоставленном примере нет объекта Group и файла в котором данные выводятся на страницу. Вы не могли бы приложить эти файлы для решения вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Все сделал! просто надо  вызвать group.getName() внутри тега